# Block tokens on someone else's address

Tags: spl-token, spl-token-program, spl

I'm looking for a way to block tokens created on the Solana blockchain. Ideally I would like to do this using Python. Please provide code samples.

Situation: I need to block an account that has my tokens (the main thing is to make it so that it cannot interact with the tokens at all).

My details for faster communication:
Telegram: @nikodim54
Discord: .nikodim10191537

Answer (score 1):

If you mean you would like to create a token where you can have freeze authority token22 has that feature.

if you are creating it in CL:

```
   $ spl-token create-token --enable-freeze
```

Comment: I already have an issued token on Dexlab. Is there any way to freeze someone else's address so that they can no longer use my token?

Comment: Yep! You can use `$ spl-token freeze <ACCOUNT_PUBKEY>` to freeze their account